Understanding Signal Protocols for Group chat, Voice, and Video call
I am new to the field of protocols and currently researching the Signal protocol and its security features. So far, I have studied X3DH, Double Ratchet, the Sesame algorithm, and PQXDH, which is detailed on Signal's site here.
Can anyone help clarify which protocols Signal uses for group chats (is it Sesame?), as well as for voice and video chats? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
